# Cannot open include file: 'boost/bind.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I get the error mentioned above. However, I only get the error in a specific build config.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/mem_fn.hpp>
```

Complete error message:

> C:\Users\opunktschmidt\source\Workspaces\RAT\dev-branch\myproject\stdafx.h(61,10):
> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/bind.hpp': No such file
> or directory

Boost is installed via the Nuget package manager.

Of course I've already googled but all I get as a suggested solution is the setting "Additional Include Directories" should be set correctly. I'm pretty sure all my build configs are identical.

This does work (Release x86):
[image]

This not (Debug x86):
[image]

Comment: Please show the error message(s) as text verbatim.

Comment: I have added the full error message

Comment: Maybe the relative path is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, an absolute path doesn't work either

Comment: What is Excellfc Debug? Can you provide complete build information without personal privacy? Include `------ Build started: Project: XXX Configuration: XX`